# Can an object call JAXB to unmarshal into itself (or, 'this')?

Tags: java, jaxb, this, self

Currently I'm calling `jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal()` to get my data back into an object. Can an unmarshaller unmarshal the data into itself?

Is this possible?

```
public class Test {
    public Test(String xmlPath) {
        //...

        // Can I point the method to inject into 'this' somehow?
        jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(xmlPath));

        //...
    }
}
```

I'd like to migrate eventually to a singleton, I'd rather not create an object and pass it to a copy constructor (and maintain that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You may have a case where that might be useful, but remember that in general the XML document unmarshals into a tree of objects that would need to be pre-created in exactly the right shape. I have never seen a real-life case where you would know exactly the shape of the XML document, so I am not surprised that this is not an option in the API.